# Cumulative Count by Category in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to get Cumulative count of rows in a Table for each month.

Suppose I have a Table like this:
[image: Source Table]

I am looking for this output:
[image: Result]

For eg : As per the Source Table, the count for **Proj1** in **Jan** was **2** and **Feb** was **1**.
But I want the Count to be shown in **Feb** as **3**, I want the Cumulative count.

I tried using DATESYTD, but its not giving the cumulative count. 
The below example too giving me incorrect values : 
[image: Eg]

Can someone advice me where I am going wrong ? Help will be much appreciated.

Thank You,
Pratik

Comment: Is doing it in Power Query an option? Would be the easiest way.

Comment: Yes Please, I can give it a try

Comment: @Marco_CH, Can you please tell me how ?

Comment: @Pratik can you please provide the sample data in table [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow). Stack does not encourage putting pictures in the question.

Comment: Smpa, in my answer you'll find the data in binary format.

Comment: @Marco_CH many thanks for that. However, stack expects OP to provide the data in the required format while asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
let
        Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCijKzzJU0lFyBGIDQz0gMjIwMgJyvBLzFICMWB2EGieoGiOYGrfUJGQ1ICFnqBpjmBrfxCJdNHNcCNhlDBRyJcIuNwJ2gcxxJ8IuDwJ2mQCFPF0IWAZS5IXLslgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, ID = _t, Date = _t, #"Date(Short)" = _t]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"ID", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Date(Short)", type date}}),
        #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Category", "Date(Short)"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Category", Order.Ascending}, {"Date(Short)", Order.Ascending}}),
        #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Row", 1, 1),
        RunTotal = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Running Total", each let Group=[Category], Row=[Row] in
                            List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Row]<=Row and [Category]=Group)[Count])),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(RunTotal,{"Count", "Row"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "OtherCol", each "Just random string"),
        #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom", {{"Date(Short)", type text}}, "de-CH"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom", {{"Date(Short)", type text}}, "de-CH")[#"Date(Short)"]), "Date(Short)", "Running Total", List.Sum),
        #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"01.01.2022", "01.02.2022", "01.03.2022"})
    in
        #"Replaced Value"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I've updated the code. The update contains the data, so you can copy the whole procedure and check each step.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is is possible to get the result via DAX too ?
I can try this method, but the original table has some other columns too which are being used on other Visuals. But I can Duplicate this table keep the required columns and follow your step as well. I am glad that I have a solution for now.

Comment: You can keep every required column you need. See update. I've created a random column. Pivot doesn't delete the "untouched" cols like `group`.